# How to create a new openerp modules

Tags: javascript, python, web-services, openerp-7

I am new in OpenERP. I need to create a new OpenERP7 Point of Delivery(POD) module. I want to know what are all the possible ways (Either full python code or web services way)?
I want to write in webservices + javascript way. So that I can easily integrate the module with mobile app also.
Please guide me where I can get all the default web services provided by OpenERP and other relevant information .

I am ok to do with full python code. However I do not have clear ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer if you go through the following link and try to create a basic module first..
http://rsuna.blogspot.com/2013/08/how-to-create-basic-module-in-openerp-7.html

The above link contains a step by step guide to code and create a basic erp module.

Once you get in the flow you can continue exploring more...

Hope it helps you...!!